# cannot import name requests python

Tags: python, python-requests

Why is that when I run this script do I get the error "cannot import name requests"

I have already run "pip install requests"

```
from bzrlib import branch,requests, json

def x:

        url = myURL
        data = json.dumps({"one": "two"})
        r = requests.post(url, data)

        print r.json
```

Comment: You have a syntax error here; `def x:` needs to have an argument list (can be empty).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to import *`bzrlib.requests`*, not the top-level package `requests`. The same applies to `json` here.

Move the imports to *separate lines*:

```
from bzrlib import branch
import requests
import json
```